# Aligning an iframe with the associated onclick buttons

Tags: css

I have an iframe that opens the corresponding web pages with the onclick buttons, but it doesn't align with the div tag even though the entire function is located in the div tag.  The buttons align properly but the actual iframe aligns to the far left of the page.  I've tried several style variations and div classes but nothing is working.

```
<div class="section">

<button onclick="myFunction1()">Illustrators</button>

<button onclick="myFunction2()">Tech Writers</button>

</div>
<div class="frame">

<script>
var iframeExists = false;

function myFunction1() {
var x
if (!iframeExists) {
  x = document.createElement("IFRAME");
  iframeExists = true;
} else {
  x = document.getElementsByTagName("IFRAME")[0];
}
x.setAttribute("src", "http://www.oldgamer60.com/Project/Illustrators.php");
document.body.appendChild(x);
}

function myFunction2() {
var x;
if (!iframeExists) {
  x = document.createElement("IFRAME");
  iframeExists = true;
} else {
  x = document.getElementsByTagName("IFRAME")[0];
}
x.setAttribute("src", "http://www.oldgamer60.com/Project/TechWriters.php");
document.body.appendChild(x);
}
</script>

</div>
```

Comment: **"with associated onclick buttons"** where do you want to display your iframe exactly??

Comment: @Rohit416  I've been trying to get them aligned with the section DIV. .section {
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     width: 60%;}